# How do you remote trigger builds with parameterized choices in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, build, parameterized

I have a build with mulitple parameterised choices

[image]

How do trigger these Parameterized choies?

I have tried to enter the /buildWithParameters URL with said choice but it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Build witb parameters [Remote Execution](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-parameterized-builds#2-remote-execution).

Answer (score 0):

See `Launching a build with parameters` section in [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build):

```
http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&REQUESTED_ACTION=greeting
```

Comment: I think its my choice encoding as I have spacing so I assume I add in %20

Comment: %20 is the URL-Encoded character for space. If your value has a space character, replace it with %20. If your value is `Greet User`, URL would be `http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&REQUESTED_ACTION=Greet%20User`